# Sort based on datetime object inside of the list

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of "snapshots" which look like this

```
{ description: "sdoiajosdi", "startDate": datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 16, 22, 47, 50, 609000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), Tags: [ {'sdklapsijd':'asdjiosoid'}], ownerId: "osjdaiosjd" }
```

These are stored in a python list. Is there a way I can sort ascending or descending based on the 'startDate' property for each item in the list? So if I have 100 snapshot objects, with differing datetime.datetime properties, can I use this as the 'sorting key?' How can I do this?

Comment: Of course. Just provide an appropriate `key=` argument to the `sort()` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899/how-do-i-sort-a-list-of-dictionaries-by-a-value-of-the-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `datetime` objects are comparable, you should just be able to sort the list with:

```
sorted(snapshots, key=lambda x: x["startDate"])
```

Comment: That looks like what I was just reading! Thanks :)